# Predictive search matches array elements non-case sensitive, does not display when case is incorrect

Tags: javascript, match, case-insensitive

I know by the title that this sounds strange but I am searching through an array in a predictive search kind of way and when I enter letters (str), the case does not matter (when I enter 'b' it finds both 'b' and 'B' for "Bears" and displays them in a list so I know that is working.... but when I don't have the correct case, it does not highlight the text in yellow. So, when I type 'B' it highlights the 'B' in the list for "Bears".... but when type 'b' it shows the 'B' for "Bears" in the list but does not highlight it.

```
    var strArray = ["Bears", "Giraffes", "Donkeys", "Monkeys"];
  for (var j=0; j<strArray.length; j++) {
    if (strArray[j].toLowerCase().match(str.toLowerCase()) && $return.length < 8) {
      var $h = strArray[j].replace(str, '<span class="prediction-text">'+str+'</span>');
      $return.push('<li class="prediction-item">' + $h + '</li>');
    }
  }
}
```

Does this make sense? I know I am not too far off. I tried changing my array to lower case, but when it displays in the predictive dropdown, it is in lower case and I don't want that....

I know it has something to do with the:

```
if (strArray[j].toLowerCase().match(str.toLowerCase()) && $return.length < 8) {
```

Line and maybe something else has do be done with that.

Thanks for the help all. You are all amazing and I really appreciate it very much.

Comment: The first argument to `.replace()` is expected to be a regular expression, and by default it will be case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This makes sense but I am not sure of what the alternative is other than .replace().

Comment: You can use a regexp: `.replace(new RegExp(str, "i"), ... )` — the "i" flag tells the regexp matcher to ignore alphabetic case. (Only works for Latin 1 code page, I think.)